# Grails 2.1.1 - Change default injected log object from commons.logging.Log to slf4j.Logger

Tags: grails, logging, dependency-injection, slf4j

I've a Grails project where I replaced Log4j with Logback. Now I also want to use the `org.slf4j.Logger` instead of `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` class for logging. How can I change the default `log` object which is placed by Dependency Injection to every Controller/Service/Domain class?

I searched within the `BuildConfig.groovy` and `Config.groovy` files but I couldn't find any configuration for this? I also looked at `grails-app/src/templates/artifacts/Controller.groovy` but I still couldn't find any place where this could be configured...

Shure, I could get my own instance of an `org.slf4j.Logger`, but then I'd have to declare it within every class like

```
private static Logger lbLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class)
```

and that's not what I want - I'd love to just replace injected `Logger` object.

Does anybody have any suggestions on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recall how the log object been injected, but anyway you can inject your own logger into controller, service or domain object.

```
In BootStrap:
def doWithDynamicMethods = { applicationContext ->
        // def logger = SLF4J new instance
        application.controllerClasses.each { controllerClass ->
             controllerClass.metaClass.getLogger = {-> logger }
        }
  }
```

This is the idea, sorry I don't have the Grails env now so I can not make a workable code.

Comment: thanks for your answer... do you speak from a Plugin point of view? Would this "dependency inject" the `logger` I define into each `Controller` class?

Comment: I got the solution, or better to say an advice which showed me the right direction from Graeme Rocher over at the grails-user mailinglist: you have to work with `AstTransformer` (see here: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-logging/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/logging/LoggingTransformer.java) and implement it as a `java` class within a plugin... but even if I know what to do, I don't know how I can develop such a plugin...

Comment: I created a Plugin with an ASTTransformer class which changes the injected `log` object from a `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` to a `org.slf4j.Logger` instance. But if I'd like to add something (instead of replacing or changing the already existing object) I'd go your way. Thanks a lot!